# Use only for downloading: FTP vs HTTP in my server?

Tags: download, protocols

I want to get some files from my computer (text, video, images) and I'd like to download them to a folder on my Android device. I have been looking for alternatives and I think that there are two ways for doing that, but I don´t know if there is a great difference in using one or another.

Which protocol is better and why, FTP or HTTP, in my case? I don`t need uploading anything, and the size of the files is not too big. (I guess around 5M the biggest file)

I think HTTP is easier and FTP is fastest, could be? But I would like, thinking in programming, which is better.

Comment: TCP works on a different, lower, layer to HTTP. It's a protocol both FTP/HTTP use for establishing sessions.

Comment: Sorry, I made I mistake when I wrote TCP, I wanted to say FTP. I have modified now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend HTTP. It allows you downloading file with multiple connections, you can easily share urls and you would also be able to download it in a restricted environment where all the ports except http are blocked.

FTP is more suitable if you want to control access to files on per user basis and require good amount of uploading also.

Addition:

You can implement security in http also using .htaccess files. However, it is not very scalable and not suitable for too many users with different access rights.

There are several other methods of protecting file on http. You will be able to find a lot of open source utilities on http://sourceforge.net which will let you do that. When speed is concerned, http is best. It allows you to fetch arbitrary part of the file and hence it is possible to have a multi thread download.

You will notice that most of file sharing sites use http and it is so for scalability reason.

Comment: Thanks, but what about security? FTP allows login and password, but http?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of speed, for file sizes larger than roughly 10kB both are equivalent. The difference is that FTP sends pure, raw data on its data channel without any headers so it has a slightly smaller overhead. But HTTP sends only around 12 or so lines of text as header for each file before blasting raw data onto the channel. So for files of around 10kB or less, yes HTTP overhead can be quite high - around 1% to 2% of the total bandwidth. For large files, the dozen or so lines of HTTP header becomes negligible.

FTP wastes one socket though for the control channel so for lots of users HTTP is twice more scalable. Remember, your OS has a limited number of sockets that it can open.

And finally, the most important consideration is that a lot of people access the internet through firewalls. Be it corporate, or school or dormitory or apartment building. And a lot of firewalls are configured to only allow HTTP access. You may find sometimes you can't get access to your files because of this. There are ways around this of course but it's one additional hassle you have to think about.

---

**Additional answer:**

I saw you asking about access restriction and security. The slight downside with HTTP is that you need to write your own web app to implement this. Web servers like Apache can be configured to do this just by writing a configuration file using HTTP basic authentication.

Luckily, people have had this problem before and some of them have written software to do this. Google around for "HTTP file server" and you'll find many implementations. Here's one fairly good open source web app: http://pfn.sourceforge.net/

Also, if you really want security you should set up SSL/TLS for your server regardless weather you end up using FTP or HTTP.